# Why do Fortnite's building hotkeys not work?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite, I changed one hotkey: sprint from left-ctrl to 'r'. All of my hotkeys have been working fine until today when I could only press f1 of my building keys, only '1' and '3' of my numbers, and all of my keys; and then I had to scroll to access the other building and item choices.
FYI: I just downloaded the season 4 update.
What is going on here?

Comment: When you downloaded the update it may have overwritten your keybind config. Check to make sure those are the same.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill they are. I even changed them to something and changed them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem: I needed to plug in my hard drive that fortnite's latest update was downloaded on. This also fixed my problem where I couldn't repair.